# GNU Radio | Packet Encoder/Decoder alternative

Tags: gnuradio

Are there any alternatives for packet encoder/decoder (deprecated) in gnuradio3.8.0.0 ?

Comment: I don't think this is really on-scope as asked here, but let's see: a) it's not deprecated in 3.8, it's been deprecated in 3.7 and *removed* in 3.8 (sorry, had to get that off my chest – it was a big relief to remove that). b) when you go into your GNU Radio instatallation's examples (e.g. /usr/share/gnuradio/examples, or wherever they are installed to), you'll find digital/packet/, with a couple of examples of how to use the header/payload demux infrastructure for this purpose.